# Adding phasers to Block variables

Tags: traits, raku

On the trail of [this question by Codesections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663606/control-phasers-from-a-trait), I'm trying to add a phaser to a variable using traits. Something like this:

```
my &doing-good is Block will enter {
    .add_phaser: "ENTER",
            {
                    if Backtrace.new.grep: { .subname  ~~ /bad/ } {
                            fail("Not authorized to call this");
                    }
            }
};
```

This fails with `is trait on &-sigil variable not yet implemented. Sorry.`

I arrived to this because there seems no way to declare that as a block; by default is a `Callable`, and `add_method` does not work on Callables, apparently. Any other way of doing this?

Comment: Phasers only exist on blocks.  You cannot "add a phaser to a variable".  I'm unclear as to what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I meant to a variable that contains a Block, of course.

Comment: But your code is only defining a variable that can contain a `Callable`, but does not initialize it?  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I wanted the variable to contain a Block, actually without initializing it.